# Can I change TV inputs with the Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one

I'm trying to use the Xbox One as my "universal remote" as much as I can, but there's one thing I can't seem to do with it - change TV inputs. I've seen it done on my parents' system via the SmartGlass remote, but the same button doesn't do the same thing for me.

I think the difference is that my parents are using their TV's built-in speakers, while my audio is output through a mini stereo system that my Xbox One is configured to control. When I use the input switch button on my SmartGlass, the stereo changes inputs instead of the TV.

Can I force the Xbox One to send input changes to the TV instead, or would I have to lose control of the stereo for that option?

Comment: by input do you mean turning the tv on and off?

Comment: @Rapitor No, I mean switching the TV from e.g. HDMI-1 to HDMI-2. I still have a PS3 hooked up that I'd like to play now and then, and I'd rather not have to go back to my regular TV remote whenever I need to switch between the two.